# How to use NyquistPlot without having a transfer function model?

Tags: plotting, control-systems

Could anyone tell me how to use `NyquistPlot` with a first argument that is not a transfer function model? The expression I'd like to pass to `NyquistPlot` is `Exp[z]Cos[z]`.

Comment: What does the expression represent? A sinusoidal transfer function, discrete-time transfer function, something else? eg, try Off[TransferFunctionModel::npnd]
NyquistPlot[Exp[z] Cos[z], SamplingPeriod -> 1] if it's a discrete-time system with sampling period 1.

Answer (score 1):

Nyquist plots usually require rational functions (i.e., ratios of polynimials). I suppose if you know what you are doing, you could approximate this with a Taylor series expansion:

```
NyquistPlot[Normal[Series[Exp[z] Cos[z], {z, 0, 6}]]]
```

[image]